# How to use python request to upload excel file and other parameters at the same time？

Tags: python-requests

##### I tried to upload excel file and other parameters at the same time.

##### I checked the body of this request in kibana as follows:

```
{
    "utf8":"✓",
    "key":"11111",
    "form":{
        "field_1":"value_1",
        "field_2":"value_2",
        "import_from":{
            "tempfile":"#\u003cFile:0x00007f879ef8bda8\u003e",
            "original_filename":"demo.xlsx",
            "content_type":"application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "headers":"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"form[import_from]\"; filename=\"demo.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n"
        }
    }
}
```

##### I tried the following request build：

1. **The first attempt：**

```
data = {
    'utf8': '✓',
    'key': key,
    'form': {
        "field_1":value_1,
        "field_2":value_2
    }
}
xls_file = {"import_from": (excel_name,
                            open(excel_path, 'rb'),
                            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")}

r = session.post(url, data=data, files=xls_file)
```

--> Server returns status 500

2. **The Second attempt：**

```
data = {
    'utf8': '✓',
    'key': key,
    'form': {
        "field_1":value_1,
        "field_2":value_2,
        "import_from": (excel_name, 
                        open(excel_path, 'rb'), 
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    }
}
r = session.post(url, data=data)
```

--> Server returns status 500

##### I think my request parameter format is wrong.

- In the target request body, the excel is a value in the `form` dictionary.

##### How do I use python requests to construct this request?

Comment: Have you tried using `requests` to do this? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @mechanical_meat

Yes. 

I have tried to build requests, but the server returned 500. 

I guess the format of my request parameter is wrong. I want to know how to handle this kind of compound parameter structure with nested files. 

The details of what I tried have been updated to the question.